# Add into mysql tablerow

Tags: mysql

In my database i have a table called **description** where as it sound has a description for an item. for example **The cake is lie**. If i now want to add a new line of text after the last word **lie**, before that i want to add **a** so that the whole line becomes **the cake is a lie**, is this possible?

For reference there are several rows in the table and i want to add a specific word after the last word in the description row for all the lines on that table.

Comment: I updated and corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just have to insert a string before the last word you can use this:
`UPDATE description SET item = CONCAT(LEFT(item, CHAR_LENGTH(item) - CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item, ' ', -1))), 'a ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(item, ' ', -1));`
This will update every String in the description table and inserts `a` before the last word.